# Android native app authentification with WordPress users

Tags: android, wordpress, authentication

I am making a native Android app. I have a WordPress website with a few users. I want my WordPress user to log in my app using the same login and password. I would like a very fluent login process without any webview or web browser.
Is it possible ? What would you recommend ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. All actions you want to preform from app side, i recommend to add those actions as ajax functions on wordpress side (it is much cleaner and organized that way - and you can base your communication on json like that ). Regarding logic, you can achieve it using two different ways:

- Lets say that you want to implement an application which will allow user to, register, login, and create posts.

### **1st way**

```
 class App {

    public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_registerUser', array( $this, 'registerUser' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loginUser', array( $this, 'loginUser' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_createPost', array( $this, 'createPost' ) );
    }


    public function registerUser() {
        //obviusly, you dont need any kind of auth over here
    }

    public function loginUser() {
        $username = //collect,sanitize data from post
        $password = //collect data from post

        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
        if( wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass ) ) {
             //preform what you need to preform
             //construct successful result array
        }
        else {
            //populate result array with an error or something
        }
        wp_send_json( $result );
    }

    public function createPost() {

      $username = //collect,sanitize data from post
      $password = //collect data from post
      //collect rest of the data related with post by itself

      $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
      if( wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass ) ) {
           //insert post, construct successfully array 
      }
      else {
          //populate result array with an error or something
      }
      wp_send_json($result);

    }


}
```

As you can see in example above, you can register as much ajax functions as you want and within each of those you can have user check and password check which is going to work just fine. Point is that, for each action you want to preform from your mobile app, you will need to send an username/password (you can store these on first successful login on app side) with other parameters.

**2nd way**
Same example above, with one difference. You can (during first login request from app side), on php side generate unique guid which you can save inside wp database, and return it to your app side (where you can save it on your app side). For each next request, you can send that guid and username from app side, confirming that user is already login and can preform privileged actions. There is no a lot of difference (from perspective of performance, I think that in both of the cases you will need to execute one query only - from perspective of auth, you can preform some testing in order to confirm this [WP_User class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L0) ). Second method is valuable if you need to identify different login sessions from one end to another (if application crashed and you want to check on your side does user want to preform login while he/she is already "logged in", or you want to forbid login in from more then one application per user. )